# How can I override System.Type.GetProperties()?

Tags: .net, reflection

I would like to override the [`System.Type.GetProperties()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aky14axb(v=vs.110).aspx) method to return one specific property only, depending on logic determined at run time. For example, if I have this class:

```
class A
{
    public int PropertyOne { get; set; }
    public int PropertyTwo { get; set; }
}
```

and if I make this call:

```
var myProperties = typeof(A).GetProperties();
```

I would expect `myProperties` to contain only one `PropertyInfo` object.  This object would contain information about either `A.PropertyOne` or `A.PropertyTwo`, but not both, depending on runtime logic.

I tried to create a type that derives from the abstract `System.Type` and to override `GetProperties()` in my derived class.  However, I always get a compile-time error:

> 'MyNamespace.MyClass.GetProperties()': cannot override inherited member 'System.Type.GetProperties()' because it is not marked virtual, abstract, or override

How can I overcome this error and override `GetProperties()` successfully?

Comment: why you would like do it? Maybe that is a [XYProblem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I attempted to edit your question to clarify what you are asking and to provide more details.  These details, such as the actual error message, may make it easier for someone searching the web to find your question.  I agree with the commenter that you may not be attempting to solve the right problem, but I will address that factor in an answer shortly.  If I have mischaracterized what you are trying to ask, please edit your question to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in noting that `System.Type` is abstract and, in theory, you can derive from it and override its abstract or virtual methods.  However, in practice, you almost certainly should not do so.  The .NET runtime does so as needed.

In C# (as opposed to, say, Java), methods are not virtual by default.  You can only override methods explicitly marked `virtual`, `abstract`, or `override`, just as the compiler error says.  In this case, you *could* override [`GetProperties(BindingFlags attr)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x(v=vs.110).aspx), as it is an abstract method.  However, overriding the method will not likely solve your issue, and your overriding method would not be available from `typeof(A).GetProperties(BindingFlags attr)` anyway.

You may find one of these approaches more useful:

1. Call one of the overloads of [`GetProperty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Type.GetProperty(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.  For example, `typeof(A).GetProperty("PropertyOne")` would return the `PropertyInfo` object corresponding to `A.PropertyOne`.
2. If none of the `GetProperty` overloads meet your needs, call `GetProperties()` as you were previously trying to do, then filter the results.  The normal Linq methods are available on the `PropertyInfo` array that `GetProperties()` returns.